# Assign branch policies to newly created repository in new project

Tags: powershell, azure-devops, azure-devops-rest-api, azure-devops-server-2020

I am currently in the process of automating the creation of a repository within a project. So far I have been successful in creating the repository, creating a main/development branch and placing prerequisite files into the respective branches.

Now I am at the point where I need to assign a branch policy to the newly created repo, keep in mind that this is within a brand new repo in a brand new project. So far I have attempted the following methods but ran into issues:

1. Attempted to assign branch policies via API call using the following documentation:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/policy/configurations/create?view=azure-devops-rest-6.0&tabs=HTTP#merge-strategy-policy

When I attempt to post to the URL given for any of these policies I see the error message as follows:
`Invoke-RestMethod : {"count":1,"value":{"Message":"The requested resource does not support http method 'POST'."}}`

2. Attempted to update the branch policies via Azure CLI, I installed the Azure CLI and acquired a personal access token. I see there are commands to accomplish getting a list of policies within a branch or editing them. However, when I try to remotely sign into our instance of DevOps I see this error:

`Azure DevOps CLI is not supported for Azure DevOps server`

I think this one may be a versioning issue since the output is telling me it's not supported. Perhaps I'm not implementing this correctly but the syntax is straight forward in what it's asking for so I don't think it's a syntax issue.

3. Last attempt was to create a branch with some standard policies on it within the new project. Then using the Update Ref API call I would use the ID of that already created branch to try and create a new branch mimicking the exact configuration of the old one. Here's the documentation I used to try this out:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/git/refs/update-refs?view=azure-devops-rest-6.0&tabs=HTTP

The post method for this one expects a relatively small payload; just the name, oldObjectID and newObjectID. However the issue I ran into here is that the old branch is out of scope while trying to create a new branch in a different repo. Even though the branch exists in a repo in the same project it still can't find the ID of the old branch and returns an unsuccessful error in the output: unresolvableToCommit

Comment: The REST API works fine. It's likely that you are calling it incorrectly. Please update your question to include the exact REST API you are calling and what your request body looks like.

Comment: Thank you, I retried it with Postman and realized I didn't need the configuration ID within the URL. It's working as expected now.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I have attempted calling the Azure DevOps REST API "[**Configurations - Create**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/policy/configurations/create?view=azure-devops-server-rest-6.0&tabs=HTTP#merge-strategy-policy)" via Postman and PowerShell script to set merge strategy policy for a new branch in a new git repository on Azure DevOps Server 2020, and the REST API can work well as expected.

Below is a sample I attempted on my side.

#### Calling the REST API via Postman:

[image]

#### Calling the REST API via PowerShell:

```
$pat = '{PAT}'
$base64AuthInfo = [Convert]::ToBase64String([Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes(("{0}:{1}" -f "", $pat)))

$headers = New-Object "System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary[[String],[String]]"
$headers.Add("Authorization", ("Basic {0}" -f $base64AuthInfo))
$headers.Add("Content-Type", "application/json")

$uri = "https://{instance}/{collection}/{project}/_apis/policy/configurations?api-version=6.0"

$body = '{
    "isEnabled": true,
    "isBlocking": true,
    "type": {
      "id": "fa4e907d-c16b-4a4c-9dfa-4916e5d171ab"
    },
    "settings": {
      "allowNoFastForward": true,
      "allowSquash": true,
      "scope": [
        {
          "repositoryId": "{repositoryId}",
          "refName": "refs/heads/main",
          "matchKind": "exact"
        }
      ]
    }
  }'

Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $uri -Headers $headers -Body $body -Method POST | ConvertTo-Json -Depth 10
```

#### Result:

[image]